# Which commits am I currently merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

When I execute`git merge`, no new commit are created yet (because of conflicts or `--no-commit` option), how to check which branch I am merging?

`git status` shows only current branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `git merge` that has stopped due to conflicts leaves two<sup>1</sup> files with information about what is being merged:

```
.git/MERGE_HEAD
.git/MERGE_MSG
```

(replace `.git` with the output of `git rev-parse --git-dir` if needed, e.g., if you're in a sub-directory within the git directory).  The contents of `MERGE_HEAD` is the other SHA-1, even if you're merging a branch by name;<sup>2</sup> but the contents of `MERGE_MSG` contains the branch name if there is one.  For instance:

```
$ git merge --no-commit origin/master
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ cat .git/MERGE_HEAD
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f
$ cat .git/MERGE_MSG
Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
```

(I had to use `--no-commit` here since there was no conflict).

(If there is no branch name in either file, but the `MERGE_HEAD` file's SHA-1 matches some existing branch tip, that would be a suitable branch name for many or most purposes.  If it matches multiple branch tips—i.e., if a single commit is the tip of several current branch names—any of those could be suitable.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a third file, `.git/MERGE_MODE`, which tells git that you're in the middle of a merge in the first place.  It's often empty, though.

<sup>2</sup>You can merge by raw SHA-1, or any other way to specify a commit.  There's no requirement that the merge be from another branch.  For that matter, you can be in "detached HEAD" mode when making a new merge commit as well, so there's no requirement that the merge be into a named branch.

Comment: Ive found `git log --oneline --left-right --merge` useful too

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple one-liner to find this out, and it works even if you're in a subdirectory and/or in a git worktree created by the `git worktree` command:

```
git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD
```