# Get MERGE_HEAD in pre-merge-commit hook

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks, git-revision

In `pre-merge-commit`, I need the hash of the merge head to verify a few things about the commits that are about to be merged to the current branch.

However, it seems that neither the reference `MERGE_HEAD` nor the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD` exist at the time when the hook is running.

How can I get the merge head revision in my hook?

Comment: If the file has been removed, the answer is "you can't": that's the only place the information was stored and until the merge commit itself exists, that's the only place Git could have extracted them from. It seems a bit odd that Git should remove this before the hook finishes though.

Comment: @torek It seems that the file is not so much removed as not created in the first place. I did some tests and the file seems to always be present if the merge is interrupted in any way: the flag `--no-commit`, a merge conflict or a non-0 exit code of a hook. It is there even if the commit is stopped by a rejected message which is definitely checked after the `pre-merge-commit` has run.

Comment: Aha, that makes more sense. The merge code has the `git commit` action built in to it, so it won't need to make the file if it goes to make the commit on its own. It's ugly but I suppose you could have your pre-merge-commit hook reject the merge to force a separate commit in which the file exists. You might consider modifying Git to provide the missing information *to* the pre-merge-commit hook (by adding the file, or adding it as an argument) and see if you can get the Git developers to take that as a change to the next Git release.

Comment: @torek Heh, I've looked into the code and it seems that the file is always saved during preparation but it is done after the hook is called. (https://github.com/git/git/blob/79f2338b3746d23454308648b2491e5beba4beff/builtin/merge.c#L893) Maybe it would be enough to just move this line a little higher? I would maybe made a pull request but getting enough know-how on the project to do that properly would take me the whole weekend so I'll pass. Too bad they've disabled GitHub issues :-(

Comment: Yep, moving it up a bit would probably work fine. Note that there's a whole process involved in submitting changes. I used GitGitGadget, which makes parts of this less painful (and other parts more painful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally Git has a function [`write_merge_heads`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79f2338b3746d23454308648b2491e5beba4beff/builtin/merge.c#L893) that finds the correct object and writes it to the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.
Unfortunately, this function is called after the [`pre-merge-hook`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79f2338b3746d23454308648b2491e5beba4beff/builtin/merge.c#L864) was already executed. (It's called regardless if the hook succeeds or fails.)

If you're willing to have a tiny bit of extra typing each merge, there is a really simple fix.
Just `exit` from the `pre-merge-commit` hook with non-0 code if the `MERGE_HEAD` is not present.
After the merge is resumed, `MERGE_HEAD` will be there.

Here is a template for such `pre-merge-commit` hook:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f .git/MERGE_HEAD ]
then
    printf 'Cannot find the MERGE_HEAD!\n' 1>&2
    printf 'Git tends to not pass this information for the first call of the `pre-merge-commit` hook.\n' 1>&2
    printf 'Please, run `git merge --continue` or just `git commit` and it should work this time.\n' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# The actual hook's body...
```

Comment: Upvoted, but knowing my users, I could not rely on that: everything must be automatic, in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I have to do the exact same task, and I have the same issue: no `MERGE_HEAD`/`MERGE_MSG` when the `pre-merge-commit` hook is triggered.

Meaning no way to know the source commit/branch being merged to HEAD.

The only workaround so far is to use instead the [`prepare-commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) which can use `MERGE_HEAD`/`MERGE_MSG` (I use the latter to extract the source branch name, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) explained [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912095/6309))

Of course, there are drawbacks:

- the biggest one is that this "Committing-Workflow Hook" takes place *after* possible conflicts were resolved. If your hook exits `1` at this point, all the resolution would be lost.
  (the result is still in the index, but if you have to `git merge --abort` as a result of the hook denying the merge... said index would be cleared)
- it is triggered for every commit, merge or not, so you need to test the case where `MERGE_HEAD` does not exist, and `exit 0`.
- it will slightly slow down the execution of every commit (instead of just a merge commit), because it needs to spawn the `prepare-commit-msg` hook. This is mainly visible on Windows.

Comment: I don't see that topic discussed in the [Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/?q=MERGE_HEAD+pre-merge-commit) at the moment (Dec. 2022, post Git 2.39)

Comment: I have walked this road before and I recommend to turn back. In my case the only thing lost was a commit message which you had to retype in some cases and it still was too annoying.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the merge head revision in my hook?

By using the [environment variable `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_miscellaneous), which, in case of a merge, will be something like "`merge mybranch`".

So `"${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION#* }"` is enough to extract the branch name, even tough its content is supposed to be human-readable".

---

The following illustrates the use of `"${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION#* }"`, while adding information on the nature of the `pre-merge-commit` hook.

I thought a failed status would mean the merge is cancelled, but no:
`exit 1` in that hook leaves the merge "in progress".

If you need to actually abort the merge, the hook has to call itself (in background) and wait one second (for the main hook process to exit, and for Git to deny the merge.
That second call should execute `git merge --abort`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

root="$(pwd)"

src="${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION#* }"
dst="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

if [[ "${abort}" == 1 ]]; then
    echo "Abort merge between '${src}' and '${dst}'"
    git merge --abort </dev/null
    cmd /d /c "exit"
    exit 0
fi

echo "------"
echo "PRE-MERGE-COMMIT (${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION})"
echo "------"

# Should not happen, but test it just in case
if [[ "${src}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "no merge in progress for this commit"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Merge from '${src}' to '${dst}'"
# if you decide to prevent the merge:
export abort=1
"${0}" >&2 </dev/null &
exit 1
```

`"${0}" >&2 </dev/null &` is the self-call. The `pre-merge-commit` exits with status 1, `git` acknowledges the merge is denied (but leaves it pending), and then, one second later, the same `pre-merge-commit` script (called in background) aborts the merge for good.

The `cmd /d /c "exit"` is used when the hook is triggered from a Windows CMD session in order to force the CMD prompt to appear.
Otherwise the `echo "Abort merge between '${src}' and '${dst}'"` is displayed... and you would need to type <kbd>enter</kbd> to find the prompt again (because that echo is done from a background process).

Comment: According to git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables, GIT_REFLOG_ACTION is supposed to be a human-readable text. Can we really assume it can be reliably parsed and it won't change format between Git releases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250480/discussion-between-vonc-and-piotr-siupa).